# Dealing with weird URLs when retrieving their images ssl.CertificateError: hostname doesn't match and UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, utf-8, urllib

So I have roughly 6600 image URLs that I want to read them from a pickle file in order to download their images locally. The two main problems I could not solve:
1) URLs that throw `UnicodeEncodeError` error. I tried many available solution online and none worked so I ended up forgetting about that URL but I prefer if there is a way to hack it. This is URLs that contain Chinese of Polaska characters for example.
2) The other error is as follows (one example):

```
ssl.CertificateError: hostname 'www.straitstimes.com.sg' doesn't match either of 'gp1.adn.edgecastcdn.net', 'gs1.adn.edgecastcdn.net', 'ne1.adn.edgecastcdn.net', 'www.uship.com', 'www.bluefly.com', 'www.belleandclive.com', 'is.belleandclive.com', 'connections.cochlear.com', 'assets.pokemon.com', 'www.shopperschoice.com', 'www.biznessapps.com', 'cdn.shocho.co', 'secure.hibustudio.com', 'www.stardoll.com', 'adn.wiredrive.com', 'www.speedtest.net', 'www.cduniverse.com', 'ak-site-origin-cover.cduniverse.com', 'cover.cduniverse.com', 'g.cduniverse.com', 'www.renttherunway.com', 'cdn2.navexglobal.com', 'www.chdist.com', 'www.thefanorama.com', 'cdn2.mediasilo.com', 'cdn.citadoncw.com', 'www.woodcraft.com', 'marketing-admin.upsight-api.com', 'www.edgecast.com'
```

It happened when I needed to download the image from https://static.straitstimes.com.sg/sites/default/files/styles/x_large/public/articles/2017/09/23/ST_20170923_WONZ_3440048.jpg?itok=-iG-zSvr as you see the image is available.

I wonder how my code below could be modified to overcome these two issues rather than try except phrase.

```
import pickle
import urllib.request
import re
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote
# img = urllib.request.urlopen(quote(value))
# img = urllib.urlopen(quote(value))
import time
count = 0

with open('images.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    b = pickle.load(handle)

print(len(b))
for key, value in b.items():
    print(value)
    print(key, value)
    #value = iriToUri(value)
    if value != 'NA':
        count += 1
        print(value)

        try:
            img = urllib.request.urlopen(quote(value,  "\./_-:"))
            #img = requests.get(value)
            split = urllib.parse.urlsplit(value)
            extension =  split.path.split(".")[-1]
            print(extension)
            if extension.lower() == 'jpg':
                filename = "immigration_images/" + str(key) + ".jpg"
            elif extension.lower() == 'jpeg':
                filename = "immigration_images/" + str(key) + ".jpeg"
            elif extension.lower() == 'ico':
                filename = "immigration_images/" + str(key) + ".ico"
            else:
                filename = "immigration_images/" + str(key) + ".png"

            img_extension = img.info()['Content-Type']
            #print(img_extension)
            if img_extension:
                if 'jpeg' in img_extension:
                    filename = "immigration_images/" + str(key) + ".jpeg"
                elif 'jpg' in img_extension:
                    filename = "immigration_images/" + str(key) + '.jpg'
                elif 'png' in img_extension:
                    filename = "immigration_images/" + str(key) + '.png'
                #urllib.request.urlretrieve(value, filename)

            urllib.request.urlretrieve(value, filename)


        except (urllib.error.ContentTooShortError, urllib.error.URLError, urllib.error.HTTPError, UnicodeEncodeError) as e:
            print(e)
            continue

print(count)
```

I am using `Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)` in `CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)`

trackback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scratch2/news_bias/test_pickle.py", line 39, in <module>
    img = urllib.request.urlopen(quote(value,  "\./_-:"))
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 564, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 756, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 694, in do_handshake
    match_hostname(self.getpeercert(), self.server_hostname)
  File "/scratch/sjn/anaconda/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 327, in match_hostname
    % (hostname, ', '.join(map(repr, dnsnames))))
```